# Processing XML document

Tags: xml, scala

I'm have the following XML document and I'm trying to build a filter that returns the contents of the  element (if exists) from within the  element.

So far I have the following code:

```
val xml = XML.loadString(output)
val ports = xml \\ "ports"
```

I then think I need to do something like this to build the filter but I can't get it to work as I would expect.

```
for (port <- ports \\ "port"){
    println(port \\ "port" filter{ _ \\"script" exists } \\ "script")
  }
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 6.40 scan initiated Tue Mar 25 14:14:09 2014 as: /usr/local/bin/nmap -&#45;datadir /usr/local/share/nmap -&#45;script=ssl-cert -p 443,80 -v -oX - www.adobe.com -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap"
         args="/usr/local/bin/nmap -&#45;datadir /usr/local/share/nmap -&#45;script=ssl-cert -p 443,80 -v -oX - www.abc.com"
         start="1395756849" startstr="Tue Mar 25 14:14:09 2014" version="6.40" xmloutputversion="1.04">
    <scaninfo type="connect" protocol="tcp" numservices="2" services="80,443"/>
    <verbose level="1"/>
    <debugging level="0"/>
    <taskbegin task="Ping Scan" time="1395756849"/>
    <taskend task="Ping Scan" time="1395756849" extrainfo="1 total hosts"/>
    <taskbegin task="Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host." time="1395756849"/>
    <taskend task="Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host." time="1395756849"/>
    <taskbegin task="Connect Scan" time="1395756849"/>
    <taskend task="Connect Scan" time="1395756849" extrainfo="2 total ports"/>
    <taskbegin task="NSE" time="1395756849"/>
    <taskend task="NSE" time="1395756849"/>
    <host starttime="1395756849" endtime="1395756849">
        <status state="up" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
        <address addr="111.111.111.11" addrtype="ipv4"/>
        <hostnames>
            <hostname name="www.abc.com" type="user"/>
            <hostname name="www.abc.com" type="PTR"/>
        </hostnames>
        <ports>
            <port protocol="tcp" portid="80">
                <state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
                <service name="http" method="table" conf="3"/>
            </port>
            <port protocol="tcp" portid="443">
                <state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
                <service name="https" method="table" conf="3"/>
                <script id="ssl-cert" output="placeholder text">
                    <table key="subject">
                        <elem key="commonName">www.abc.com</elem>
                        <elem key="organizationalUnitName">Info</elem>
                        <elem key="stateOrProvinceName">London</elem>
                        <elem key="countryName">UK</elem>
                        <elem key="organizationName">ABC Incorporated</elem>
                        <elem key="localityName">London</elem>
                    </table>
                    <table key="issuer">
                        <elem key="commonName">VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3</elem>
                        <elem key="countryName">US</elem>
                        <elem key="organizationalUnitName">Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10</elem>
                        <elem key="organizationName">VeriSign, Inc.</elem>
                    </table>
                    <table key="pubkey">
                        <elem key="type">rsa</elem>
                        <elem key="bits">2048</elem>
                    </table>
                    <table key="validity">
                        <elem key="notBefore">2012-11-04T00:00:00+00:00</elem>
                        <elem key="notAfter">2014-11-23T23:59:59+00:00</elem>
                    </table>
                    <elem key="md5">0b96b21786ab67c5531cff08cf044c6b</elem>
                    <elem key="sha1">b3cd7fec0ade71acb0fe83be5e723495313ff426</elem>
                    <elem key="pem">-placeholder</elem>
                </script>
            </port>
        </ports>
        <times srtt="106198" rttvar="99430" to="503918"/>
    </host>
    <runstats>
        <finished time="1395756849" timestr="Tue Mar 25 14:14:09 2014" elapsed="0.70"
                  summary="Nmap done at Tue Mar 25 14:14:09 2014; 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.70 seconds"
                  exit="success"/>
        <hosts up="1" down="0" total="1"/>
    </runstats>
</nmaprun>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering for `script` isn't really necessary since `\\` will traverse the entire structure and return those elements that match.

```
xml \\ "script"

res1: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<script id="ssl-cert" output="placeholder text">
...
```

Print the `script` tags in `res1`

```
res1.foreach(println(_)) 

<script id="ssl-cert" output="placeholder text">
<table key="subject">
...
```

**Update regarding comments**

To get only the `port` nodes that contain `script` nodes

```
(xml \\ "ports" \\ "port").filter(n => n.descendant.exists(_.label == "script"))
```

Outputs:

```
res81: scala.xml.NodeSeq =
NodeSeq(<port protocol="tcp" portid="443">
                <state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
                <service name="https" method="table" conf="3"/>
                <script>
                    <table key="subject">
                        ...
```

`descendant` gives a `List[Node]` which is one way to do  it. There are others but that worked for me.

Comment: Arr - I get it now! If I wanted to return the corresponding port number for all the port elements that contains a <script> element, can I do this?

Comment: @user1513388 It's similar. You get all the `port` elements and then get the `portid` attribute. To get an attribute you specify it with `"@attribute"`. So, that becomes `xml \\ "port" \\ "@portid"`.

Comment: OK so I can get all of the port elements, but I assume will need some kind of a filter to then get only the port elements that contain a script element?

Comment: @user1513388 Yes, you can use `filter` or `exists` to get only the `port` nodes that contain a `script element. See updated answer.

Comment: @user1513388 It's there now. :)

Comment: Excellent - Thanks for your help. Jumping from Python to Scala is a bigger learning curve than I thought.

Comment: `scala.xml` probably isn't the best place to start with Scala. Try to understand `map`, `filter`, and other operations on collections before using them for XML.